# Use an id for the Buttons of Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing in Extjs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have this code :

```
this.rowEditor = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
     clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
     autoCancel: false,
     errorSummary: false,
     listeners: { .....
```

And I would like an id on each button ( save and cancel button) ... Is it possible ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: In the html code, i would like a id for the cancel button et un other on the save button ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add ids for each button like below :

```
 tbar: ['->', {
                xtype: 'button',
                icon: BASE_URL + 'assets/images/save.png',
                id: 'save-id',
                tooltip: 'Save',
                scale: 'medium',
                hidden: false,
                handler: function() {

                }
            }, ' ', {
                xtype: 'button',
                id: 'cancel-id',
                enabled: false,
                hidden: false,
                icon: BASE_URL + 'assets/images/cancel.png',
                tooltip: 'Cancel',
                scale: 'medium',
                handler: function() {

                }
            }]
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about id but you can get the button like below code snippet:-

```
your_grid.getPlugin('your_plugin_id').editor.down('button[itemId=update]');
your_grid.getPlugin('your_plugin_id').editor.down('button[itemId=cancel]');
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The question is how to put an id on the buttons.